# instanceof in java on a nested array list

Tags: java, string, arraylist, instanceof

How come i get an error at the if statement, what can i do to find the datatype the nested array list can hold?

```
ArrayList<List<? extends Object>> table;
table = new ArrayList<List<? extends Object>>();
table.add(new ArrayList<String>());
if( table.get(0) instanceof List<String> ){
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `instanceof` with a generic type. Generic types are erased at runtime.

Comment: To be clearer, you cannot do _anything_ like you're trying to do.  Given the code you've provided, `table.get(0)` is an empty `ArrayList`, and knows _nothing_ about the type of elements it might have been supposed to have.

Comment: Is there any alternatives as i need to know before adding string or integer in the arraylist

Comment: The alternative is to not design your program to mix `ArrayList`s of different types in the first place.  There's your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can create two subclasses of ArrayList for String and Integer, and check for them:

```
public class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {
   //Add needed constructors here
}

public class IntegerList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
   //Add needed constructors here
}
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
ArrayList<List<? extends Object>> table;
table = new ArrayList<List<? extends Object>>();
table.add(new StringList());
if( table.get(0) instanceof StringList ){
//Do something
}
```

Comment: Too bad you can't accept both answers, since together they really provide all the information needed to answer this question.